# Create load failure on a 413 in Sonata Media bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I am on a project that uses Sonata Media Bundle for image uploads.

Currently, when a CMS user uploads an image that is too large for our system to handle, the upload simply stalls, without any indication of what the user has done wrong.

Is there a simple "right" way to make the application fail more loudly, thus giving the CMS user an idea of what she has done wrong? A toggled array key in the wrapping admin class perhaps?

Comment: check this question it might help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779143/add-constraints-in-upload-image-sonatamediabundle`

Comment: Thanks -- I'll take a look.